# Ada Program Hangs on Exception, gnatmake

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm having an issue with an ADA program hanging on exception. Below is a test program that I am compiling with

```
$ gnatmake divide_by_zero.adb
gcc -c divide_by_zero.adb
divide_by_zero.adb:6:19: warning: division by zero
divide_by_zero.adb:6:19: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
gnatbind -x divide_by_zero.ali
gnatlink divide_by_zero.ali
```

My version of gnatmake is

```
$ gnatmake --version
GNATMAKE 4.8.3
```

The contents of divide_by_zero.adb are

```
$ cat divide_by_zero.adb
procedure divide_by_zero is
   result : Integer;
   denominator : Integer;
   begin
      denominator := 0;
      result := 1 / denominator;
   end divide_by_zero;
```

The output of program execution is

```
$ ./divide_by_zero.exe

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : divide_by_zero.adb:6 divide by zero
** Program hangs, Ctrl-C does nothing, Ctrl-D does nothing
** I have to go to Task Manager to stop divide_by_zero.exe
```

I was wondering whether anyone else had an issue with an ADA program compiled under gnatmake version 4.8.3 hanging on *any* type of exception? Is there something wrong with my ADA code? Is there something wrong with my install? I'm running the code on cygwin, currently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine and works fine (i.e. raises exception and exits :-) in Debian 8, gcc4.9.1.

```
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$ gnatmake divide_by_zero.adb 
gcc-4.9 -c divide_by_zero.adb
divide_by_zero.adb:6:19: warning: division by zero
divide_by_zero.adb:6:19: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
gnatbind -x divide_by_zero.ali
gnatlink divide_by_zero.ali
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$ ./divide_by_zero

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : divide_by_zero.adb:6 divide by zero
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$
```

So I believe the Cygwin installation is broken.

It may be worth having the Gnat-2014 Libre edition for testing, though I'm presuming the FSF compiler is your preference because of license conditions.

Alternatively there are at least 2 ways of getting a working FSF Gnat compiler targetting Windows.

I have successfully built Windows commandline applications on Debian simply by installing the gnat-mingw-w64-x86-64 and running e.g.  `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gnatmake divide_by_zero.adb` (oddly enough it builds a 32-bin Windows exe, but the package runs on a 64-bit host and the executable runs fine if I reboot to Windows).

I've also heard good things about the TDM build of the FSF Gnat/GCC mingw compiler available [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) There are choices available according to whether you need to build for 32 or 64 bit Windows executables. I think you need to download both the "Ada support" package (scroll down!) and the base compiler.

If you really need cygwin, you may have to continue digging, or report this failure to the cygwin community and (politely!) push for an answer. If you do so, please update the question here.